# mixing interface types TS

Tags: typescript

Having a TS issue which I thought would be simpler to implement than it is. I have an interface which describes an object of key/values, the majority strings with one exception.
Its a long list something like

```
export const list = {
   itemOne: 'bla',
   itemTwo: 'bla bla',
   itemThree: 'bla bla bla',
   itemFour: false
```

}

I want an interface for this without explicitly typing out each item, something like

```
import { list as keys } from 'the_above'

interface listTypes { 
    [key: string]: string;
    [`${keys.itemFour}`]: boolean;
}
```

I get this error message, which I don't fully understand
'A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.'

Any help would be appreciated as I'm still shaky with TS

Comment: Could you just have the value be a string or number ?  `[key: string]: string | number`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to prevent the compiler from widening the types of the values in your `list` object: the compiler will infer the literal values instead. This is important in regard to how the compiler [infers the type of the template literal string](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#inference-with-template-literals) for the key with the `boolean` type value.

Also: TypeScript offers another way to define types that represent objects (data structures with indexed values): a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases). The TS handbook section [Differences Between Type Aliases and Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces) begins with this information:

> Type aliases and interfaces are very similar, and in many cases you can choose between them freely. Almost all features of an `interface` are available in `type`, the key distinction is that a type cannot be re-opened to add new properties vs an interface which is always extendable.

If there's not a reason that you need to keep the type open to be mutated by other code, then a type alias might be a better choice in this case.

Here's an example:

> Note: in the playground and code shown below, I've enabled the compiler option [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) for stronger type safety. See also the utility type [`Record<Keys, Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type).

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2jAvDA3gKBjBUCmAtgPJj4BcMA5AEZwCGVANNrgYQCoDuIltDMOoxY48RDgAsATvgrUhggUOasxhAGIgArlMoAzenAj4WAXxj0IMUJCgBuTAHpHAPTfu3Tx9fDJLxqSgEcEwvGEkkXCsAKy0-GAgEMABzOHwYAAcGAE9kqW0wABMYPQQ0pgSQGDAqsnxiqCqEQgyQQPIw5tbAjHgkWEsYAGt8bKtzPXzCaigJfAB9ehoQADd8KgcbZBGx1D7oB0wobIz0gBl+jhP8KzQAJXxQKUKAHmgpJOSK98+APhgAGQwB5PV4AAwAJOhjqcQHphqMIABtKhqTQ6KgAXVMYIqyxAaXoYF+hxh50u1wA0qMAOp4CQAIRABPwRIAaoYtOk0Ds4RhWEjWDhKbgwAjsnyLtArqcrIMpVAZTckZTMTB8AAPAhFKz4wlgIU4GAAfhglMNOEoZDWUlYmMoWjAQxqXDADlMh0KjwYMh8tmGlAVSup2TpsyZLPZnPwDiNcfjzhcxtCXuAPvSW1gcEDFNlDjgADoDEYY14k6FC1ApFyHInk5hC0SQLN8FIAAr5U6BbK11zJoA)

`module1.ts`:

```ts
export const list = {
  itemOne: 'bla',
  itemTwo: 'bla bla',
  itemThree: 'bla bla bla',
  itemFour: false,
} as const;
//^^^^^^^^
// const assertion
```

`module2.ts`:

```ts
import { list as keys } from './module1';

type ListTypes = Record<string, string> & Record<`${typeof keys['itemFour']}`, boolean>;
```

Here are some example statements showing compiler inference: they illustrate that the type represents what you asked about in your question:

```ts
type ListTypeKeyWithBooleanValue = keyof {
  [
    K in keyof ListTypes as ListTypes[K] extends boolean
      ? K
      : never
  ]: unknown;
};

declare const k: ListTypeKeyWithBooleanValue;
            //^? const k: "false"

declare const l: ListTypes;
l.false;
//^? (property) false: boolean

l.true;
//^? string | undefined

l.anotherProperty;
//^? string | undefined
```

Comment: Thanks jsejcksn. Life saver